SharePoint 2013 search not crawling site
Our SharePoint 2013 search is no longer crawling our sites data. It reports 1 successes for the top-level site and that is it.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have tried to re build search multiple times via powershell and through the gui with no success... it will crawl the user site with no issue

This question is not about programming. For SharePoint administration, please post in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/
